# flex skin for datagrid cannot be found

Tags: datagrid, air, skin

I defined one componnet that extends bordercontainer,and Add some display object.
when i popup the container,it throw error like this,"skin for datagrid cannot be found."

it is weired.
the container as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" backgroundAlpha="0" backgroundColor="0xffffff"  
                verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="100%" height="100%">

    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">

        <s:VGroup gap="20" verticalAlign="middle" left="0" right="0" width="100%" height="100%" >


            <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" 
                      paddingTop="8" id="contVGroup"
                      paddingBottom="8"
                      paddingLeft="8"
                      paddingRight="8"
                      width="100%" height="100%">


                <s:DataGrid id="datagrid" editable="true" width="100%" height="100%"/>

            </s:VGroup>


        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: code looks ok. are you sure that error is related to this datagrid (any others in app)?

Comment: btw, you have datagrid nested inside 5 containers - why not just place datagrid inside bordercontainer?